# HTaccess remove query string at start of URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using a translation system that is currently not working for non-friendly URLs such as

```
/index.php&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=&product_type_id=1&product_type_1_Height_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_Height[0]=Short+%28up+to+80cm%29&product_type_1_Strain_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_Strain[0]=Asia-Central&product_type_1_Yield_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_Yield[0]=High
```

So I've added:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /es/(.*)index.php(.*)$ http://www.seed-city.com/$1
```

... into my *.htaccess* file to redirect to the English version. However, it adds `?lang=es&url=` to the front of the URL after being redirected to the English version and I'd like to be able to remove it. It can also be `?lang=fr&url=` `?lang=de&url=` `?lang=zh-CN&url=` etc.

I've tried as much as I can think of but I haven't been able to remove it successfully. Thanks for your time and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Natastna2.

EDIT:

@vbence Thanks for your reply. I'd like to take this url:

```
http://www.seed-city.com/?lang=es&url=index.php&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=&product_type_id=1&product_type_1_seed_type_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_seed_type[0]=Regular&product_type_1_indoor_flowering_time_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_indoor_flowering_time[0]=Medium+%2856+to+90+days%29&product_type_1_Outdoor_harvest_time_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_Outdoor_harvest_time[0]=Middle+of+September
```

and change it to:

```
http://www.seed-city.com/index.php&option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=&product_type_id=1&product_type_1_seed_type_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_seed_type[0]=Regular&product_type_1_indoor_flowering_time_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_indoor_flowering_time[0]=Medium+%2856+to+90+days%29&product_type_1_Outdoor_harvest_time_comp=find_in_set_any&product_type_1_Outdoor_harvest_time[0]=Middle+of+September
```

removing the `?lang=es&url=` from the beginning. This is because now, if someone clicks the Spanish translation button once, it redirects to the English version fine as it matches my previous rule of:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /es/(.*)index.php(.*)$ http://www.seed-city.com/$1
```

However, if they click it once, the URL now starts with ?lang=es&url= and therefore does not match with my previous rule. On their second click on a translation flag, they are taken to the error page rather than the English version which I would prefer. This is why I am trying to remove the query from the front of the URL. The resulting URL should be devoid of language identifiers as it is in the English default language.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Still not clear what criteria you have, what exactly you want to achieve? Please give some examples what URL should the user see in their browsers and to what real URL it has to be traslated. - And use formatting if possible.

Comment: @user689061 Your first URL does not have a beginning, it is only a the query string.

Comment: @vbence I'm sorry, it wouldn't let me post any more hyperlinks. If you could just add h-ttp://www.seed-city.com/ to the start of it, then that's the correct URL.

Comment: @user689061 I don't think it is possible the way your example suggests, because the second url has nothing which would suggest the language. **es** completely disappears, so you could not recreate the first one from the second.

Comment: I am OK with there being no mention of the language in the second URL, I'm trying to remove all mention of the languages. Thanks, Ant.

Comment: You can not change the URLs in your HTML page source with mod_rewrite, if this is what you want.

Comment: @vbence Ahh, is that why this doesn't work: RewriteRule ^/index.php index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]   I was hoping that would remove it but it didn't.

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange in the future.  Did you manage to find a solution?  If so, please post an educational answer for the benefit of future researchers. This question appears to be abandoned and represents an information deadend for those whom are seeking a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide `lang=foo` and simulate a directory like `/foo/index.php`, you can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/index.php index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

*Note that I assumed that you use this rule in a .htaccess file. In apache config the URL will start with a `/`, so you have to add it right after the `^` character*.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to simulate a directory. I just want to remove this: ?lang=es&url= from the start of the URL. I tried using: RewriteRule ^/index.php index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L] but that hasn't worked. Thanks again, Ant.